# Wordpress removed incorrrectly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have removed my wordpress website from localhost to webhosting.

One of my plugins used custom images and they are not shown now.
The way to the image, plugin tells is http://onstars.ru/onstars/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/wp-content/themes/sparkling/images/vk.png

The way I need is http://onstars.ru/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/wp-content/themes/sparkling/images/vk.png (without onstars, it was on the localhost)

How to tell a plugin to change this?

The only code about it in plugins files is as follows:

// Directory of either custom icons or the packaged icons

```
if ( isset( $options['custom_icons'] ) && $options['custom_icons'] == 'url' && isset( $options['custom_icons_url'] ) ) {
    // Custom icons expected at a specified URL, i.e. //example.com/blog/uploads/addtoany/icons/custom/
    $icons_dir = $options['custom_icons_url'];
    $custom_icons = true;
} else {
    // Packaged 16px icons
    $icons_dir = $A2A_SHARE_SAVE_plugin_url_path . '/icons/';
}
```

Comment: Did you try to reupload the images via wordpress media upload?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update path information in your Wordpress `wp-config.php` configuration file, it's located at the root of your Wordpress installation.

See [this guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) for more information, specifically chapter two its sections on [moving folders](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_plugin_folder).

Answer (score -1):

In case there is no other feasible solution you can try:

```
str_replace('onstars/', '', $your_image_url)
```

on this example:

```
$icons_dir = str_replace('onstars/', '', $options['custom_icons_url']);
```